# CSV Download not working on Kindle Fire for Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

- I have a method that downloads a csv file, and it has worked on my
  other android and windows devices.

```
  Future<void> export(List<List<dynamic>> data) async {
    // Convert the CSV data to a string
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDateTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss').format(now);
    String csvString = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(data);
    String fileName = 'scout_$selectedMode$formattedDateTime.csv';

    try {
      // Get the Downloads directory
      Directory? downloadsDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      if (downloadsDirectory == null) {
        print('Error: Downloads directory not available.');
        return;
      }

      // Construct the file path
      String filePath = path.join(downloadsDirectory.path, fileName);

      // Write the CSV string to a file
      File file = File(filePath);
      await file.writeAsString(csvString);
      print('CSV file exported successfully to: $filePath');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error exporting CSV: $e');
    }
  }
```

- Additionally, I make sure to request permissions and have those
  stated in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- However, when I download on the kindle, the function returns `CSV
  file exported successfully to:

  **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.scout/files/scout_Pit2024-03-13__00-01-40.csv**

This is the correct file name and everything, but when I later check the Kindle Fire internal storage on my Windows File Explorer, that file or directory is nowhere to be found. What may be the issue here, because this worked on my other Android devices.